# Setting bootstrap-select value with array but preserving array order (instead sorting alphabetically)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-select

This should be simple and common, but my Google skills are failing me.

I'm using `bootstrap-select` to create a dropdown menu where users can select up to 3 options, initialized like so:

```
$('#PItypeSelect').selectpicker({
    maxOptions: 3,
});
```

Let's say this is the HTML:

```
<select id='PItypeSelect' multiple>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
</select>"
```

And now I'd like to set the selected options from an array, for example `tipo = ['B','A','C']`, but no matter what I try, it always ends up being displayed as `A, B, C` instead of `B, A, C`.

Neither

```
$('#PItypeSelect').selectpicker('val', tipo);
```

nor

```
$('#PItypeSelect').val(tipo);
$('#PItypeSelect').selectpicker('refresh');
```

work, and I've had no luck googling this issue. Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible out of the box. You'll want to follow https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/2119.